# May one learn commentaries of permitted texts on Tisha B'av?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav, job-iyov-book-of, lamentations-eicha

Regarding texts one is permitted to learn on Tisha B'av like Eicha and Iyov, is one allowed to learn the various meforshim as well or only the texts themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch 554:2

> ומותר ללמוד מדרש איכה ופרק אלו מגלחין וכן ללמוד פירוש איכה ופירוש איוב:

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an English translation...and presumably mutar as well ;)